# Dealing with securing an ICE server to allow only allowed IP addresses to access it

Tags: node.js, webrtc, stun, turn, ufw

I am trying to figure out the best way to secure an ICE server for WebRTC calls. At the moment, the server allows all traffic through the necessary ports (say, 4000:8000) that are required for Coturn to work. Currently, when a source user calls a target user, the negotiation takes place directly with the ICE server:

[image: img1]

I would like to ensure that that ports 4000:8000 are available only to the source and target user, not to the outside world. To do this, I've shut down all ports, including 4000:8000 with `ufw` and spun up a small Nodejs server script on the same ICE server script on a different port (say, 3000). I've opened this port up to my backend server's IP address. In other words, only one port (other than port 22) is opened, and the only traffic allowed in is from my backend.

With this in mind, I've come up with a "hacky" way to ensure that the source user and target user can access my ICE server. When the source user initiates the call, a request is made to the backend, which, knowing the IPs of both users, in turn sends a request to port 3000 to my ICE server. Then, the ICE server dynamically creates rules for these two IP addresses, allowing access to ports 4000:8000. Upon success, the target user then tries to directly access the ICE server (as in the first diagram) and, ultimately, create a negotiation with the target user:

[image: img2]

Upon disconnection, a similar request is made from my backend to the ICE server to remove these IPs from the list of firewall rules. How do I dynamically update these rules?

```js
// creating rules
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

const addToFw = async ({ ips }) => {
    // in the diagrams, I use 'sourceUserIpAddress' and 'targetUserIpAddress', but
    // here it's just an `string[]` of IPs. Same idea, though.
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
            const ip = ips[i];
            if (ip) {
                execSync(
                    `echo "y" | ufw allow from ${ip} to any port 3478`
                );
                execSync(
                    `echo "y" | ufw allow from ${ip} to any port 4000:8000 proto tcp`
                );
                execSync(
                    `echo "y" | ufw allow from ${ip} to any port 4000:8000 proto udp`
                );
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error in addToFw', err);
    }
};
```

```js
// removing rules
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

const getResults = (ip) =>
    execSync(
        `ufw status numbered |(grep '${ip}'|awk -F"[][]" '{print $2}')`,
        ''
    )
        .toString()
        .split('')
        .filter(Number);

const removeRulesForIp = (ip) => {
    let results = getResults(ip);

    const occurences = results.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < occurences; i++) {
        let ruleNumber = null;
        if (i === 0) {
            ruleNumber = results[0];
        } else {
            results = getResults(ip);
            ruleNumber = results[0];
        }

        // should always be defined
        if (results[0]) {
            execSync(`echo "y" | sudo ufw delete ${results[0]}`);
        }
    }
};

const removeFromFw = ({ ips }) => {
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
            const ip = ips[i];
            if (ip) {
                removeRulesForIp(ips[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error in removeFromFw', err);
    }
};
```

Why am I doing `let results = . . .` and using `execSync`? I've noticed that if I use an asynchronous approach and `Promise.all`, then `ufw` seems to not be able to handle that. I guess `ufw` can handle ***only one rule creation/deletion operation at once***.

So, with all that out of the way, onto the actual question. Will this scale with hundreds of thousands of concurrent users? What if, say, 10,000 people simultaneously click the "call" button? Will `ufw` skip some requests to create/delete rules?

Also, I'm aware that I can store (in a database on my backend) and check whether or not a user's IP has changed since their last call (and remove the old IP address from my ICE server only in the event that it did), but let's say I don't do that. Are there any caveats?

Is this a feasible solution and approach to the problem or is there a better way? Or perhaps this is a feasible approach, but there are some things that I should change.

Comment: The usual way is for the TURN server to require some authentication token, which your backend can generate and pass to the client. Are you sure you want to block at the firewall level rather than simply authenticate at the application level?

Comment: I know I've tagged `TURN` in this question (I couldn't find the `ICE` tag), but my ice server urls, which are setup on the client, are prefixed with `'stun:'`. At the moment, I would assume that if a STUN negotiation fails, so will the call (no fallback to TURN)

Comment: Yeah, I used shorthand; STUN and TURN can both require authenticated requests.

Comment: Odd, I was able to successfully see `Done` in the [Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) app without any authentication for `stun:<ip-address>:3478` (when Coturn ports are all opened to everyone). Only with `turn:<ip-address>:3478` did I need to provide my credentials

Comment: If you have not configured your STUN/TURN server to _require_ authentication, then yeah, it won't. Also note that STUN is optional, and ICE may finished successfully without neither STUN nor TURN under the right network conditions.

Comment: I will further look into this. [Would this](https://whatsapp.turn.io/docs/api/authentication) be the correct documentation on how to generate such an access token? I ask because I see `whatsapp` in the URL

Comment: That seems to have absolutely nothing to do with anything except the generic word "turn". No, start at the coturn project site if you're using the coturn server: https://github.com/coturn/coturn. I'm not quite sure where they're hiding their detailed setup instructions, but this is definitely the correct starting point.

Comment: FWIW: stun is unauthenticated because it is less than 100 bytes and typically done on a single port. And without STUN you can not even know the clients public IP are so you can not configure your server for it because the server is required to discover them.

TURN is authenticated because it is actually gives access to heavy resources. But even there (and mind you that TURN also needs to run over TCP and TLS) doing IP-based restrictions are you plan are uncommon.

Comment: So then what's the point of securing TURN if STUN will always be available at the specified ports without credentials anyway? I found [this](https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/MVIWb3DOuMg/m/jWtkhDrLTsgJ) resource which explains it a little bit, but all I'm trying to do here is avoid someone trying to bombard my open range of ports with DoS attacks.

Comment: TURN has the permission mechanism which is essentially a built-in way of doing what you are trying to achieve: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766#section-8